# How install test version of package for MacTeX?

Tags: packages, installing, mactex

The `babel` maintainer has suggested that I try an as-yet unreleased version to see if it removes an incompatibility with another package.

I downloaded the requisite files. If I use `latex babel.ins`, then immediately I get messages that it is trying to overwrite the existing, stable, versions already in the texmf tree that were installed as part of and previously updated with the TeXLive Utility app.

How can I extract `babel.sty` and the other files from `babel.dtx` so as to allow me to place them in the same folder as my source document where I'm testing things?

And will latex, run from TeXShop, then automatically find those versions even though I have not installed using the TeXLive Utility app?

Comment: You can set the `\basedir` in `docstrip.cfg` to a local `texmf` tree. On macOS this would be `~/Library/texmf`. You can use `tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME` to add other directories. How to do that in detail should be in the documentation for `docstrip` and `tlmgr`

Comment: @DG': I put a copy of `docstrip.cfg` in the same directory as `babel.ins`, `babel.dtx`, etc., but changed the `\BaseDirectory` line to be `\BaseDirectory{/Users/murray/Library/texmf}`. Now when I run `latex babel.ins` there, I get error `I can't write on file `/Users/me/Library/texmf/tex/generic/babel/babel.log`. As yet, there is no `babel` subdirectory of `/Users/me/Library/texmf/tex/generic/babel/`, What am I doing wrong?